# can not open 'rails console' after 'gem install searchlogic'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, searchlogic

```
lhdgriver@lhdgriver-1015PW:~/prog/social$ bundle show searchlogic
/home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28


lhdgriver@lhdgriver-1015PW:~/prog/social$ rails console
/home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method `merge_joins' for class `Class' (NameError)
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:8:in `block in included'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:7:in `class_eval'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:7:in `included'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic.rb:34:in `include'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic.rb:34:in `singletonclass'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic.rb:34:in `<class:Base>'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic.rb:33:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /home/lhdgriver/prog/social/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
    from /home/lhdgriver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't ever have this error but generaly with a sudo bundle install this kind of problem will disappear.